# Non-exhaustive patterns in function max

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci

In ghci this code :

```
let max [] = error "maximum of empty list"  

let max [x] = x  

let max (x:xs)   
    | x > maxTail = x  
    | otherwise = maxTail  
    where maxTail = max xs
```

Causes error : `*** Exception: <interactive>:26:5-106: Non-exhaustive patterns in function max`

What is the non-exhaustible pattern here? The zero elem, single elem and multi elem list are catered for ?

Update : 
[image]

Update 2 :

[image]

Update 3 :

Works as expected on Debian (Raspberry Pi) :

[image]

Comment: There's no `:{` and `:}` in your screenshot.

Comment: It looks correct now. I'm a bit confused why it didn't insert "Prelude|" before every line though. Maybe there's some weird interaction between WinGHCi and multi-line mode and/or pasting.

Comment: I use WinGHCi but I've never been able to get multiline pasting into it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using three separate `let`s, you're defining three separate, non-exhaustive functions named `max`, each one shadowing the previous ones. In order to define a multi-case function using `let`, you use the `let` keyword ones and then just repeat the function signature at the same indentation for each pattern like this:

```
let max [] = error "maximum of empty list"
    max [x] = x
    max (x:xs)
      | x > maxTail = x
      | otherwise = maxTail
      where maxTail = max xs
```

In order for this (or any other piece of code that takes up multiple lines) to work in GHCI, you'll need to start multi-line mode by entering `:{` and then exit it afterwards with `:}` or write it all in one line using `;` instead of line breaks (except before `|` where you'd just write `|` without a `;` or line break in front).

Comment: You can also write this on one line by delimiting definitions with a `;`.

Comment: @sepp2k tried your code, including entering multi line mode but receive error : "<interactive>:74:56: parse error on input ‘=’"

Comment: @blue-sky So did I and I didn't. Curious. Did you add any additional indentation? Which line was the error on?

Comment: @sepp2k I've updated question with screenshot, is ghci version same ?

Comment: Alternatively use `:set +m` to allow multiline definitions. (Or use [IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell) the [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) kernel)

Answer (score 1):

GHCi (and in general, `let`) doesn't allow you to define a function this way. You simply defined 3 functions, overwriting one with another each time.

If you want to keep using GHCi, write something like this:

```
let max list = case list of
    [] -> error "maximum of empty list"  
    [x] -> x  
    (x:xs) -> 
      if x > maxTail then x else maxTail  
      where maxTail = max xs
```

Comment: `let` *does* allow you to define a function with multiple patterns, you just need to write `let` only once. But more importantly GHCi does not allow you to write code that takes up multiple lines unless you use `:{` and `:}`. So your suggestion won't work without that either.